# Unable to get value from JNI GetMethodId function

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I am unable to call java method in .cpp file. JNI function GetMethodID returns null value.

My .java file:

```
public boolean connectedState(boolean status) {
    return status;
}
```

My .cpp file:

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jboolean
JNICALL Java_com_android_myapplication_MainActivity_getJniString( JNIEnv* env, jobject obj){

    jstring jstr = (env)->NewStringUTF("This comes from jni.");
    jclass cls=(env)->GetObjectClass(obj);
    jclass clazz = (env)->FindClass("com/android/myapplication/MainActivity");
    jmethodID connectionState = env->GetMethodID(clazz, "connectedState","(Ljava/lang/String;)Z");
    jobject result = (env)->CallObjectMethod( obj, connectionState, true);

    const jboolean str = (env)->GetBooleanField(result, NULL); // should be released but what a heck, it's a tutorial :)
    // printf("%s\n", str);
    if(str) {
        //return (env)->NewStringUTF("Open Success");
        return str;
    }
}
```

I am accessing the this native function in button click of activity side

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // connectedState(connect);
    boolean b= getJniString();
}
```

I am getting null value in connectionState variable in native method of getJniString().

Comment: You should learn smoe JNI basics ... `connectedState()` doesnt' take `String` as parameter so `(Ljava/lang/String;)Z` is obviously wrong

Comment: 2. if you import `getJniString` as static then `jobject obj` is a `Class` object not instance of `MainActivity`

Comment: I am sending boolean as parameter.Here (Ljava/lang/String;)Z represent boolean

Comment: basics!!! `(Ljava/lang/String;)Z` would be good for method like `boolean someMethod(String par)` ... before edit your method was `boolean connectedState()`

Comment: Then wt i need to send instead of (Ljava/lang/String;)Z.In my method booth return type and parameters are boolean.

Comment: i got crash in callObjectMethod

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field-type `Ljava/lang/String;` is wrong, because the Java method accepts `Z` `boolean`.

- the one `(Z)` means, that it accepts a `boolean` argument.
- the other one `Z` means, that it has a `boolean` return value.

It's probably rather something alike this:

```
jclass cls = env->FindClass("com/android/myapplication/MainActivity");
jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID(cls, "connectedState", "(Z)Z");
jobject result = env->CallObjectMethod(cls, mid, true);
```

And you'd have to cast the (eventually) returned `boolean` to `(jboolean)` before returning it.

see [Chapter 4. The class File Format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html), below "field descriptors".